# Render a 3D mesh face mask using the Augmented Face API in android ndk

Tags: opengl-es, arcore

I am trying to render the a mask over the face using the `AugmentedFace` API in `Arcore`. I have all the vectors containing the normal, vertices, indices and uv texture of the face. I need to render the mask using these vectors by using `OpenGL`. The mask is not getting rendered properly and it gets rendered only on the edges. Can someone please help me with the rendering in android `NDK`.